# why `sh -c "export a=1&&echo $a"` returns nothing?

Tags: linux, bash, sh

**A)** 
 first I run `export a=1&&echo $a` in linux terminal and I get 1.

```
[root@ip-172-31-16-92 ec2-user]# export a=1&&echo $a
1
```

**B)**
But when I run  `sh -c "export a=2&&echo $a"` and I still get 1 instead of 2.

```
[root@ip-172-31-16-92 ec2-user]# sh -c "export a=2&&echo $a"
1
```

What happend? If `sh -c "export a=2&&echo $a"` itself is a child process of the terminal,it should have its own **environment**, first it should make a copy of his father environment,so a=1,but when it execute `export a=2` ,environment a should be set to 2,then `echo $a` should be 2.But it returns 1,what happend?

Comment: See: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one and and you'll see it works.

```
sh -c 'export a=2&&echo $a'
```

When enclosed in double-quotes, `$a` is expanded to its current value by the shell before invoking `sh`.

Comment: so，sh -c “export a=2&&echo $a” is expanded to sh -c “export a=2&&echo 1”？

Comment: @傅继晗 Yes, exactly.